# Replacing Control Character in sed

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I need to replace all occurrences of the control character CTRL+A (SOH/ascii 1) in a text file in linux, how can this be achieved in SED?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This can be done through `cat` with the `-v` (equivalently `--show-nonprinting` options and piping this into `sed`).

If the control character the start of heading (SOH) character (CTRL+A / ASCII 1), and we want to replace it with a tab, we would do the following:

```
cat -v file | sed 's/\^A/\t/g' > out
```

`cat -v` would replace the SOH character with ^A, which would then be matched and replaced in `sed`.

Comment: the sed i was using was in a very old machine (SunOS 5.10) and this solution was the only one among the listed that worked. Thanks

Comment: That does not work if your file happens to contain the two characters ^A.  Operating directly on the control character value instead of its printed representation would be better.

Answer (score 33):

Try:

```
sed 's/^A/foo/g' file
```

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to create the `^A` sequence in the above command.

Comment: Good point on the "Ctrl-V A" shortcut. I was about to add it as a comment to my answer. I originally suggested the \x01 syntax because it's easier to copy-and-paste into scripts, and visually check that it's the correct character (in certain editors).

Comment: LOVE that  CTRL+V  thing. When I did CTRL+V+ ESC key it inserted ^[  That's great!

Comment: @dogbane any idea what `^A` means?

Answer (score 22):

By "replace", I'm assuming you want to change the file 'in-place'.

Using GNU sed:

```
# Create a file with a single control character (SOH)
echo -e "\x01" > file
# Change SOH control characters to the literal string "SOH"
sed -i 's/\x01/SOH/g' file
# Check result
cat file
```

gives...

```
SOH
```

The `-i` option doesn't work on OS X sed, so you'd need to work-around that by piping sed to a temporary file.

Comment: Actually OSX `sed` has `-i` too, although it requires an argument. Try `sed -i ''` if you don't need a backup.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. I've no idea whether it wasn't there in the version I checked, or whether I simply missed it.

Answer (score 7):

What do you want to replace them with?  If the replacement is a single character, `tr` is a better choice than `sed`.  To replace with the letter 'a':

```
tr '\1' a < input-file > tmp && mv tmp input-file
```

Comment: `tr` is the way to go. But I wouldn't recommend a one-liner unless you really test the result. You get a different result whether you single quote `'\1'` or use `\1`.

Answer (score 0):

You Can use tr command

tr -s '\001' '|' newfile

tr -s "word or delimiter" want to replace with "word or delimiter" newfile

Comment: This isn't what the OP wanted. `-s` means delete repeating chars, not replace one char with another char.