# using sed to remove special chars and add spaces instead

Tags: sed

I have a block of text i'd like to change up:

```
^@^A^@jfits^@^A^@pin^@^A^@sadface^@^A^@secret^@^A^@test^@^A^@tools^@^A^@ttttfft^@^A^@tty^@^A^@vuln^@^A^@yes^@^
```

using sed i'd like to remove all the `^@^A^` (and variations of those chars) with a few spaces.

I tried:

```
cat -A file | sed 's/\^A\^\@/  /'
```

but thats obviously wrong, can someone help?

Answer (score 3):

if you can enumerate the allowed characters then you can do something like

```
sed -e 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/ /g'
```

which will replace everything *not* in the set of alphanumeric characters with a space.

If you just want to replace all 'non-printable' characters with spaces then you can use a character class[1] with

```
sed -e 's/[^[:print:]]/ /g'
```

some older versions of sed may not support this syntax though but it is standardized in the unix specification so you should not feel guilty for using it.[2]

[1] http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq3.html

[2] http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_03

Comment: Oops. sorry, attempting to fix my vim/chrome integration I seem to have broken leading spaces. fixed.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `^A` is not two characters, but in fact just one control character. So you should write something like `\x01` instead.

Anyway, there are three character ranges, `\x00-\x1f` are control characters, `\x20-\x7f` are ascii, and others are... something that depends on encoding.

I don't know sed well, but if you want ascii only, that's how I would've done it in perl:

`head /dev/urandom | perl -pe 's/[^\x20-\x7f]/ /gi'`

Answer (score 1):

If only replace ^A and ^@, you can use this:

```
sed 's/[\x01\x0]/ /g' file
```

Then I find more similar answers in SO which already discussed.

https://superuser.com/questions/75130/how-to-remove-this-symbol-with-vim

[Replacing Control Character in sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13180057/replacing-control-character-in-sed)