# sed to replace non-printable character with printable character

Tags: sed

Am running `BASH` and UNIX utilities on `Windows 7`.

Have a file that contains a vertical tab. The binary symbol is `0x0B`. The octal symbol is `013`. I need to replace the symbol with a blank space.

Have tried this `sed` approach but it fails:

```
sed -e 's/'$(echo "octal-value")'/replace-word/g'
```

Specifically:

```
sed -e 's/'$(echo "\013")'/ /g'
```

---

Update:

Following [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13180057/replacing-control-character-in-sed) I use `GNU sed` and this approach:

```
sed -i 's:\0x0B: :g' file
```

but the stubborn vertical tab is still in the file.

---

What is the correct way to replace a non-printable character with a printable character?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replacing Control Character in sed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13180057/replacing-control-character-in-sed)

Comment: Why are you trying to use a sub-shell and echo here at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sed should recognise special characters:

```
sed -e 's/\x0b/ /g'
```

Comment: Correct, but why do you pass `-e`?

Comment: @hek2mgl: Because some versions of sed don't work without it.

Comment: Wanted to hear that! (Could imagine you are simply doing it without a reason). Can you name versions which does not support omitting `-e` ?

Comment: @hek2mgl: Some non-GNU versions, IIRC.

Comment: @choroba Tried your advice (with the -e) but 0x0B is still in the output file. For the LHS I have tried \0x0B and \x0B - but the char will not die. Will try another version of sed.

Comment: @choroba Turns out I was not using GNU sed. When I switched to GNU sed your solution worked (without -e). Also, per your advice, I use \x0B rather than \0x0B. TY.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to why the -e?  If you use more than one sed expression, then each one must be preceded by the -e.  So, for example:

```
echo foo bar bas zer | sed -e 's/zer/oh my/g' -e 's/bas/baz/'
```

would result in:

foo bar baz oh my

thus performing 2 different sed changes ('scripts) with only a single invocation.  See sed man pages for more details.

(the above example is, obviously, contrived.  I, however, have seen a sed command in a script with 78 individual -e 'scripts'!)

If you only have one 'script', then the -e is optional, obviously.